# MVC3 Different Display names for a property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a following  property on my view model:

```
[Display(Name ="Contractor Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Since I am using this view model across various places, I want to change the name of the property to "Customer Name", "Some other Name", etc. depending on the derived class. This will help me getting correct validation messages, etc.

Is it possible to do override the Name property in derived classes?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. I've done that. In the derived class just override the `Name` property and give it another annotation attribute.

Comment: Oh yes! this is better than having another fake property. Thanks much! Please add this as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment by Martin served the purpose.

> Yes it is possible. I've done that. In the derived class just override
>   the Name property and give it another annotation attribute. – Martin
>   Smith

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
public class PropertyTitle : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public int _ID { get; set; }

    public PropertyTitle(int ID)
    {
        this._ID = ID;
    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            if(_ID == 1)
               return "1";
            else if(_ID == 1)
               return "2";
            return "";
        }
    }
}

public class TestModel
{
    [PropertyTitle(2)]
    public string MyTextField { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the point? If you are going to have two different `PropertyTitle` annotations why not just have two different `DisplayName` annotations and be done with it?